# Symfony2 error when deploying

Tags: symfony

I'm new with symfony. I get this error when launch project after deploying.
Could u help me please.
Thanks

> *Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Service "fragment.renderer.inline" must implement interface "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Fragment\FragmentRendererInterface".' in /htdocs/DEV-web/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/DependencyInjection/FragmentRendererPass.php:58 Stack trace: #0 /htdocs/DEV-web/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Compiler/Compiler.php(107): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\FragmentRendererPass->process(Object(Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder)) #1 /htdocs/DEV-web/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php(593): Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\Compiler->compile(Object(Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder)) #2 /htdocs/DEV-web/app/bootstrap.php.cache(2698): Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->compile() #3 /htdocs/DEV-web/app/bootstrap.php.cache(2476): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->in in /htdocs/DEV-web/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/DependencyInjection/FragmentRendererPass.php on line 58*

Comment: Have you registered it? $app->register(new Silex\Provider\HttpFragmentServiceProvider()); http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/http_fragment.html

Comment: where i can add this?? Thank you

Comment: You're not providing any information about what you're doing, which Symfony version, if you're using Silex, whether you checked the link I provided to you. It's quite hard to support you that way.

Comment: but i'm not using  Silex. And when I test the project in local, it's work fine in prod environment

Comment: can't you provide more details about which version of symfony, where is your prod environment - why is it so hard to provide more information when you want people's help?

Comment: ooo... i'm using symfony 2.84.. i want to say it's work fine when i lanch the project localy at my pc

Comment: i think that error happen at this line at FragmentRendererPass.php

if (!is_subclass_of($class, $interface)) {
                throw new \InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('Service "%s" must implement interface "%s".', $id, $interface));
            }

Comment: and where do launch it where it isn't working? what's the difference? did you clear your cache for prod?